# Cannot Merge Two partitions on a single Hard Disk

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I deleted and formatted Dell's Recovery partition, and was hoping to add that 14GB of space to the `C` drive. No matter that I try, I just cannot get it to merge with drive `C:` I've tried using `EaseUs Partition Manager` and `Windows 7's Disk Management` itself. Any idea how this can be done? It's the Drive `H` I'm trying to add or merge to `C`.

[image]

Comment: Did you get an error when attempting to merge them?

Comment: No. I just cannot merge them. The Merge option does not appear at all.

Comment: Or, Extend in Disk Management in Windows 7

Comment: The main issue is because the c drive is a primary partition, and you're trying to merge into an extended partition

Comment: @CanadianLuke So if I converted H to a Primary Partition, would I be able to merge it to C:

Comment: It would be much easier, but you'd still need another tool, and to repair the boot records. You'd also destroy the last two partitions in the process, and possibly the c drive. I'd just create that space as a junction point

Comment: @CanadianLuke Ok, so I did it. I deleted H:, then moved the unallocated space `behind` `C:`, using EaseUs Partition Master 10.8. From there, I used Windows Disk Management Tool to extend C: into the unallocated space. That 14.x GB is now part of partition C:, and everything else works well too.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any data on drive H:, delete the partition and then extend the C:\ partition using the newly created free space.

If you need the data, then back it up to another drive before deleting the partition.

Sometimes Windows won't let you easily extend volumes, and you need to use third-party software to do so.  In my experience, the GParted boot disk has worked very well.  It can take some time to complete, based on the size of the partitions, so make sure you take that into account.  Also, you should always back up all of your data before making changes to your partitions, just in case something happens.  I personally have never lost data using GParted, but you should always back up before making changes like this.

GParted Boot CD ISO Download:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable

How to use:
http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html

Comment: I deleted it, and the option to extend the C:\ partition is grayed out.

Comment: You will need to use third-party partitioning software to extend this volume, most likely because the free space is "in front" of the partition, and not "behind" it.  I don't think you will be able to do this while Windows is running, because it will need to "move" the data in the partition to use all the free space.  I have had good results using the GParted boot disk, which will allow you to move and resize your partitions outside of Windows.  I've updated the answer with links to the download and how-to page.